# Using and developing own modules in Julia 1.6

Tags: module, julia

I am having some difficulty using my own modules in my project. My approach is the following:

I start by creating a folder called `MyProject` and a folder `src` within the `MyProject` folder. Within `MyProject/src`, I generate an empty project by executing `generate MyModule`. So far, so good.

The content of `MyProject/src/MyModule/src/MyModule.jl` is

```
module MyModule
export greet, myfunc

greet() = print("Hello World!")

function myfunc()
    print("hi from MyModule")
    return nothing
end

end # module
```

Now, this is my module. I want to use this in MyProject, so I go back to `MyProject` and activate the environment: `activate .`

To my understanding, in order to use `MyModule` in `MyProject`, I have to include it using `dev`: `dev src/MyModule`. When I write `st`, I can see that `MyProject` now contains `MyModule` - so far, so good.

I now create a file `playground.jl` in the `MyProject`-folder containing the code below, which executes flawlessly:

```
using MyModule

MyModule.greet()
MyModule.myfunc()
```

**Q1**. Is this approach correct and professional, or am I missing something in my workflow?

**Q2**. When I make changes in `MyModule.jl`, I go to `MyProject` and run `]instantiate` which compiles the changes, but tells me to `Restart julia to access the new version`. Is this really necessary, or is there a way to get the changes of `MyModule.jl` without having to restart? It seems a bit excessive and tedious that I have to restart Julia to test my changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A1**.  Yeah, that makes sense.  Probably the nicest package for this kind of project is DrWatson.jl, which [recommends (almost) exactly this approach.](https://juliadynamics.github.io/DrWatson.jl/dev/project/#Including-Julia-packages/modules-in-src-1).

**A2**.  `MyModule` should get re-compiled automatically, when you do `using MyModule`, so you don't need to go to all the `instantiate` trouble.

Also useful is [Revise.jl](https://timholy.github.io/Revise.jl/stable/), for interactive work.  You start with

```
using Revise
using MyModule
```

(Note that `Revise` must come before `MyModule`.)  Then you do some interactive work, and find something you want to change with `MyModule`.  You can just go in and change the files, then use the updated code without restarting your interactive session, or manually recompiling or anything.  Revise just automatically figures out that anything that changed will need to be recompiled, and does it for you like magic.